# Conveying 'food for thought"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> Yes, your ideas have certainly given me food for thought (i.e. they are worth thinking about)!

> Oui, tes idées m'ont bien donné matière à réflexion !

Can one use idiomatically 'matière à réflexion' to convey the sense of 'food for thought'? Are there any other idiomatic ways to express the meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Matière à réflexion* is idiomatic and matches very well the English idiom.

An alternative can be *donner à méditer* but the previous one is better here.